# Meaning of "double dose"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of *double dose*? For example,

> I wish for you a **double dose** of health.

Is it used in everyday English? What are its synonyms?

Comment: What does the dictionary tell about *double*? And *dose*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dose is a quantity of a medicine or drug taken or recommended to be taken at a particular time: "he took a dose of cough medicine".

A double dose would literally be to take two amounts at the same time, but it's usually used metaphorically. I've never used it in speech, or heard anyone else use it in everyday speech, but it is often used in [news reports](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&q=%22double%20dose%22&oq=%22double%20dose%22&aq=f&aqi=d2&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=3931l5638l0l5824l13l12l0l1l0l0l220l1721l3.5.3l11l0), for example:

- "[Irish Channel offers a **double dose** of St. Pat's celebrations](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=newssearch&cd=1&ved=0CDEQqQIwAA&url=http://www.wwl.com/content_page.php?contentType=4&contentId=10195822&fGId=16612&fGCTId=47&tempId=44122&tId=2&gId=1719&ei=peNhT5ps4tvhBMfNhJEI&usg=AFQjCNGMRLkL3QMaUXK2bCjBV29F7UHojQ)" -> this is in reference to two St. Patrick's Day block parties.
- "[Stock markets jump on **double dose** of encouragement from the Fed](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=newssearch&cd=3&ved=0CDgQqQIwAg&url=http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/markets/9142234/Stock-markets-jump-on-double-dose-of-encouragement-from-the-Fed.html&ei=peNhT5ps4tvhBMfNhJEI&usg=AFQjCNEa9o7HmqFsWsPXRY4Q_sVlhnOWhw)" -> this refers to the Federal Reserve announcing that "15 of 19 banks had enough capital to survive a deep recession and a global financial shock" as it also "acknowledged in its strongest language to date that the world’s largest economy is on the mend".
- "[Chrome patches up after **double dose** of CanSecWest pwnage](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=newssearch&cd=10&ved=0CFEQqQIwCQ&url=http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/03/09/pwn2own_pwnium_cansecwest/&ei=peNhT5ps4tvhBMfNhJEI&usg=AFQjCNHj_xHdsjKLEhS6FgW9SBTdKQYdRQ)" -> the Chrome web browser was hacked with a pair of zero-day flaws.